# cmd.exe, nested for loop, the variable cannot be use in option like skip=

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt

I have many archive folder which stores the backup files. each folder increases daily.

I need to delete all files except for recent N copies in each of them, N was defined by a variable from the parent loop.

%%a is a number from parent loop, then use another for loop to delete

```
for /F "usebackq skip=%%a" %%x in (`dir /TW /O:-D /B %%b`) do del %%x
```

The error reports

%a" was unexpected at this time.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As it is not possible to use a variable for `skip`, you need to work around that limitation somehow.

Some alternatives:

1. Hardcode the *N* (number of copies to keep) by putting the actual value in the for loops
2. Instead of using inline `dir`command to produce the list of entries implement another script that outputs only those entries you want to delete (then you might be able to set your *N* in just one place)
3. Pipe the output of `dir` to a utility which filters out the *N* lines from the beginning of the listing (I'm not aware of such, but it's possible that some of the GNU utils - of which there exists a Windows port - could do that).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable in the parameters portion of a `for` loop, just not a variable from another `for` loop. Here's a little contrived example that lists the contents of the `%TEMP%` directory 10 times, skipping one more line each time through the loop. This should be a representative example of what you're trying to do:

```
@echo off

for /l %%a in (1,1,10) do call :innerloop %%a > %%a.txt
goto :EOF

:innerloop
for /f "usebackq skip=%1" %%i in (`dir /s /a /b "%TEMP%"`) do echo %%i
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good script to write in PowerShell.

```
$n = 5

$FoldersList = Dir e:\Archive

foreach($Folder in $FoldersList)
{
    Dir $Folder | 
        Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | 
        Select-Object -Skip $n | 
        Remove-Item -whatif
}
```

In this case, Powershell makes for a very clean and easy to maintain script.

Test it before you run it on your archive because I didn't test it much on my end. Remove the `-WhatIf` when you are ready.

Comment: I cannot use Powershell because it requires security policy change in the server which I don't have the admin rights

Comment: You can start powershell like this from cmd: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy remotesigned` and the security policy is changed just for your session without changing it for the server. No admin rights needed.